IRLZ44N vs IRFZ44N performance - Driving a 12V DC motor(3 speeds) with 12V or 24V supply voltage using PWM
I am trying to run 3 speeds on a 12V DC motor with either a 12V or 24V battery using PWM. I had a working breadboard prototype based on the schematic attached, with the complete code using IRFZ44N MOSFET. The prototype worked but had a few tweaks that needed to be done. For example, The MOSFET IRFZ44N mosfet was heating up and the MOSFET was not completely turned on. The motor has some audible noise that needed some PWM tuning for the frequency since the operating frequency was 3.9kHz. All things said the prototype was working. I wanted to measure the temperature profile of the board so i mimicked the breadboard prototype into a prototype solder board and I came across IRLZ44N, similar to IRFZ44N but it was a logic level FET with lower Rdson with gate voltage of 5V instead of 10V. I substituted the FET and the prototype didn't work after that. I went back to IRFZ44N and now that doesn't work either. The gate receives only 900mV to 1.5V (regardless of which mosfet I am trying) which isn't sufficient to turn ON the mosfet.
I used a multimeter to test if the micro is getting the power and it seemed fine. I directly gave a gate signal to the button and the motor ran fine. I ordered 5 micro from Amazon and all of them had this issue and tried a new one from Digikey and had the same issue. I modified the code, tried lowering/eliminating the gate resistance and nothing has improved on the situation. I have attached the schematic, the code I used (which was working and now facing issues), and the scope images of 12V at 3 speeds measured at Vds. If you have any insights on what mistake I made and what can I do to rectify this? which MOSFET I can use to make it enter enhancement mode and fully turn on for my application, that would be very helpful.
#include <Arduino.h>

// Define the button pin, the PWM capable pin, and the voltage detection pin
const int buttonPin = 3;    // Adjust according to ATtiny85 pin layout
const int fanPin = 1;       // Corresponds to OC1A (PB1 on ATtiny85)
const int voltagePin = 0;   // PB0, used for voltage detection from voltage divider

// State variables for button debouncing
bool buttonState = LOW;
bool lastButtonState = LOW;
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;
const unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;

// Fan speed states
enum FanState {OFF, SPEED1, SPEED2, SPEED3};
FanState fanState = OFF;
FanState lastFanState = static_cast<FanState>(-1); // Initialize to an invalid state

unsigned int maxPWM = 255; // Maximum PWM value, adjusted based on voltage

// Voltage divider constants
const float referenceVoltage = 5.0; // Reference voltage (e.g., 5V)
const float voltageDividerRatio = 6.0; // Voltage divider ratio (500kΩ + 100kΩ) / 100kΩ

// Setup function to configure initial pin modes and timer settings
void setup() {
  pinMode(fanPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(voltagePin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  setupTimer();
  configureBasedOnVoltage();
  updateFanState();
}

// Set up timer for Fast PWM mode
void setupTimer() {
  // Common settings for Timer1
  TCCR1 = (1 << PWM1A) | (1 << COM1A1);
  TCCR1 |= (1 << CS10); // No prescaler
  OCR1C = 0xFF; // Set top value for maximum PWM frequency given the prescaler
  OCR1A = 0x00; // Start with a duty cycle of 0%
}

// Function to adjust fan speed with smooth transition
void setSpeed(unsigned int prevSpeed, unsigned int newSpeed) {
  // Set PWM Registers for Timer1
  TCCR1 = _BV(PWM1A) | _BV(COM1A1);  // Set PWM1A and Clear OC1A on Compare Match when up-counting
  GTCCR = _BV(PWM1B) | _BV(COM1B1);  // Set PWM1B and Clear OC1B on Compare Match when up-counting
  TCCR1 |= _BV(CS10); // No prescaler, start the timer

  OCR1C = 255; // Set TOP value for PWM frequency

  int currentValue = prevSpeed;
  int increment = 5; // Adjust the increment as desired
  if (newSpeed == 0) {
    OCR1A = currentValue;
  } else {
    while (currentValue < newSpeed) {
      OCR1A = currentValue;
      delay(30); // Adjust the delay time as needed
      currentValue += increment;
    }
  }
  OCR1A = newSpeed; // Ensure final speed is set exactly
}


// Function to update fan state
void updateFanState() {
  if (fanState != lastFanState) {
    unsigned int prevSpeed;
    switch (lastFanState) {
      case OFF:    prevSpeed = 0;    break;
      case SPEED1: prevSpeed = 60;   break;
      case SPEED2: prevSpeed = 75;   break;
      case SPEED3: prevSpeed = 90;  break;
    }

    unsigned int newSpeed;
    switch (fanState) {
      case OFF:    newSpeed = 0;    break;
      case SPEED1: newSpeed = 60;   break;
      case SPEED2: newSpeed = 75;   break;
      case SPEED3: newSpeed = 90;  break;
    }

    setSpeed(prevSpeed, newSpeed); // Smooth transition between speeds

    lastFanState = fanState; // Update last fan state
  }
}

// Function to handle voltage-based configuration
void configureBasedOnVoltage() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(voltagePin); // Read the ADC value (0 to 1023)
  float voltageAtPin = sensorValue * (referenceVoltage / 1023.0); // Calculate the voltage from the ADC value
  float inputVoltage = voltageAtPin * voltageDividerRatio; // Calculate the input voltage

  if (voltageAtPin >= referenceVoltage) { // If voltage at pin is equal or greater than the reference voltage (5V)
    maxPWM = 0; // Set maxPWM to 0 to disable PWM
    setSpeed(0, 0); // Ensure the fan is turned off
  } else if (voltageAtPin < 3.0) { // Assume 12V system if voltage at pin is less than 3V
    maxPWM = 255; // Use full range of PWM
  } else { // Assume 24V system if voltage at pin is 3V or more
    maxPWM = 100; // Limit PWM range to about 40%
  }
}

// Main loop handling button presses and fan state updates
void loop() {
  bool reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    lastDebounceTime = currentMillis;
  }

  if ((currentMillis - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    if (reading != buttonState && reading == HIGH) {
      fanState = static_cast<FanState>((fanState + 1) % 4);
      updateFanState();
    }
    buttonState = reading;
  }

  lastButtonState = reading;
  configureBasedOnVoltage();
}






Your schematic has the microcontroller's VCC pin connected to ground. Is that actually what you built?

Start with some basic troubleshooting.  Measure the gate to source resistance of your FETs with an ohmmeter to see if the gates are intact.  If that looks OK, remove the FET and see if the GPIO can drive say 1000 pF (after the 100 ohms) to the correct voltage.  That should tell you where the problem is.

Sorry yes small correction, my Vcc isnt connected to gnd on my prototype. 5V from voltage regulator directly goes to the Vcc pin

@John -  i have tested the components individually. everything seems ok. Vgs is max only 1.5V although earlier when IRFZ44N was used, I used to get 7V -10V at the Vgs. i removed the micro and have the gate directly to switch input. I will try the 1000pF with the FET removed.

How did you get 7 V - 10 V Vgs? It looks like you're driving the gate directly from the microcontroller which you are running from 5 V, and which has an abs max voltage of 6 V.  Were you driving the gate with something else?

earlier i used to use IRFZ44N which has 10V Vgs. i switched to IRLZ44N logic level FET for lower heat dissipation. Now both the Mosfets don't work for my application.
